# keyboard and mouse wont work in gui and recovery mode

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I just did a fresh install of ubuntu 12.04. 
When i get to the login screen, my keyboard and mouse won't work. 
I tried to go to recovery mode through grub but the keyboard wont work on the recovery menu GUI.
how do i go around it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Install or reinstall the input drivers:

Open a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T and copy paste following command and press Enter.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

If it is already installed, then purge and reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Answer (score 0):

Symptoms
Mouse and keyboard don't work in graphical mode of Ubuntu Unity.

Workaround

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

If you work in recovery mode you probably haven't dns
to fix it:

```
echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf
sudo apt-get install xorg
sudo apt install gdm
```

Choose gdm-light or gdm3. Both are working.